useGLTF fom React-three/drei throws "url.lastIndexOf is not a function" when used with Native
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei/native'
import BaseWhite from './base.gltf'

export default function Model(props) {
   const gltf = useGLTF(BaseWhite);
   return <primitive object={gltf.scene} />;
}

Throws an error "url.lastIndexOf is not a function" while useGLTF('assets/models/base.gltf') works perfectly (but that url is from webpack, I need metro)
Metro config is set correctly, botched config gives "Unable to resolve module".
Path seems to be correct too, wrong path gives "Unable to resolve module".
useGLTF(BaseWhite.toString())

Throws "Could not load 3: fetch for "http://localhost:8081/3" responded with 404: Not Found".
It seems to work for everyone else. Any idea what I do wrong?
